# How to check verify that SQL query was ran in transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple use case to solve. Imagine that somebody tells you "hey, this particular set of queries is not transactional!" and your job is to deny that statement. How could one do that?

Assumptions:

- user is able to reproduce this by "clicking on one magic button" which triggers, lets say 3 following `INSERTs`
- we have access to `mysql client` and all privileges
- we do not have access to code base of an application, so no integration tests possible to verify this from code perspective
- we are using `MySQL` server with `InnoDb`
- we can tweak MySQL configuration as we want (slow queries, etc.)

Comment: First, you need to establish what they mean by "not transactional" - in SQL, any DML statement will automatically create a transaction if one is not already open. Depending on the RDBMS, it may automatically commit that transaction when the statement ends, or leave it open (which of these happens may also be configurable)

Comment: Damien, what we basically mean here is simple "commit all three operations or rollback everything in case of error no matter which operation fails".

Comment: So can't you just show the code and point where you start the transaction and where you commit it?

Comment: Nope - no code access. I need to verify that transaction was rollbacked in case of error and no harm was done to data integrity.

Comment: Try with: http://d2-systems.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/global-transaction-identifiers-feature.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a transaction section in the output of:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

Which looks like (that's from my local MySQL currently not running any queries):

```
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 900
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 undo n:o < 0
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 47, OS thread handle 0x7fc8b85d3700, query id 120 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

I don't know if you can actively monitor this information, so that you can see it exactly in the moment of you 3 insert operations. You can probably use that last bullet of yours (using slow queries) here...

In addition MySQL has command counters. This counters can be accessed via:

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "COM\_%"`

Each execution of a command increments the counter associated with it. Transaction related counters are `Com_begin`, `Com_commit` and `Com_rollback`, so you can execute your code and monitor those counters.

Comment: Correct! After hitting DB twice for particular scenario I could see `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "Com_commit";` returning `2`. When error occured, I could see that `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "Com_rollback";` incremented as well from `0 to 1`. That means I can confirm that some abstract operation is transactional, thanks!